# Sequence construction that creates an empty sequence if lower is greater than upper bound

Tags: r, sequence

More than once the "cleverness" of R's `seq` function has hit me badly in the corner case when `lower == upper - 1`:

```
> 1:0
[1] 1 0
> seq(1, 0)
[1] 1 0
> seq(1, 0, 1)
Error in seq.default(1, 0, 1) : wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

I'm not asking for the reasons of this odd behavior -- I assume it's now just a legacy that we have to live with. Instead, I'd like to know if any package implements a `seq` operator that returns an empty sequence in this case, like the following:

```
safe.seq.int <- function(from, to, by=1) {
  if (from > to) integer(0) else seq.int(from, to, by)
}

> safe.seq.int(1, 0)
integer(0)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's good practice to use `seq_len(n)` instead of `1:n` for exactly this reason - if `n=0` then you get an empty sequence rather than `c(1,0)`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Exactly what I need, thanks! Haven't tried that one before. Too bad the documentation doesn't include an example for `seq_len(0)`...

Comment: An alternative is if you have a list or vector, then  for(i in seq_along(LIST)

Answer (score 9):

It's very unfortunate that both : operator and seq() function can't handle this case. The best answer I have found by far is the following:

```
seq(a,b,length = max(0,b-a+1))
```

Answer (score 5):

The rlang package implements `seq2()`:

```r
rlang::seq2(3, 5)
#> [1] 3 4 5
rlang::seq2(3, 3)
#> [1] 3
rlang::seq2(3, 2)
#> integer(0)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>