# Do programming languages have consistent interpretations of {1,...,n} when n = 0?

Tags: algorithm, oop, r, math, standards

On math.SE, a [question about math notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/154903/3733) enerated a discussion of how programming languages interpret the set {1,...,n} when n=0

The question asked for a mathematical notation to represent the R code `1:n`

According to the comments, the mathematical interpretation of {1,...,n} when n=0 is that this is an empty set. A subsequent comment suggested that C is consistent with this interpretation, because `for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)` returns a empty set because it iterates 0 times.

It is not clear to me what the equivalent statement in R is, but `1:0` returns the vector `[1,0]`

Thus, `for (i in 1:0) print(i)` iterates over 1 and 0 (I interpret as analogous to the C code above)

Is this because {1,...,n} is not the correct notation for `1:n`?

Does this mean R violates a universal rule?

Is there a consistent interpretation for this set among programming languages?

Comment: A `for` loop does not return anything at all, and does not necessarily act on a set.  It executes code in the enclosed block.  That code might, or might not, perform something akin to an enumeration.

Comment: @EricJ. I updated the code to have it do something. I excluded it before since the something was arbitrary. Does that clarify?

Comment: @EricJ. To be pedantic, in R `for()` returns `NULL` but does so invisibly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each mathematical formalism has its own notation. To suggest that there is a "universal notation" is very "un-mathematical". Look at the notation associated with tensors or groups if you want examples of mathematical domains where multiple notational systems exist.

In R the code `x <- 1:0` returns the ordered vector c(1,0). Just as the code x <- 2:-2 returns c(2,1,0,-1,-2). The code `x <- seq(1, length=0)` returns a sequence of length 0 which is printed in console sessions as `integer(0)`. R is not really designed to mimic set notation but it does have some set functions and it also has packages that more fully implement set notation.

Answer (score 4):

C has no concept of a set that a `for` loop runs over. A `for` loop `for(a;b;c) d;` is simply syntactic sugar for:

```
a;
loop: if (!b) goto done;
d;
c;
goto loop;
done: ;
```

Answer (score 4):

See also my response at: [Sequence construction that creates an empty sequence if lower is greater than upper bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922169/sequence-construction-that-creates-an-empty-sequence-if-lower-is-greater-than-up) - in R, `seq_len(n)` should be used in preference to `1:n` for exactly this reason (the latter fails misbehaves when `n=0`).

Answer (score 3):

some languages support the concept of ranges, in C it is arbitary what you make a for loop do, you could make it mean 0  or you could make it count backwards.   In other languages a range that has the second number less that the first often produces a number sequence that is decreasing.    But its arbitrary, and there is no universal rule.